How does GPTCache match input queries with cached prompts?
GPTCache (https://github.com/zilliztech/GPTCache) reduces the number of used tokens and response latency by caching user queries and the corresponding results from LLM. When determining whether a cache hit occurs, it searches for the k most semantically similar prompts in the cache to the current user query. Then it determines if the cache hit occurs and returns the desired answer to the user. I wonder what is the difference between the scenario when k=1 and k>1?
In typical scenarios, users usually receive only one answer rather than multiple. Therefore, the situation where k>1 appears to be no different from k=1. I have checked the official website of GPTCache, but I did not find a clear answer.

The readme says GPTCache employs embedding algorithms to convert queries into embeddings and uses a vector store for similarity search on these embeddings. This process allows GPTCache to identify and retrieve similar or related queries from the cache storage, as illustrated in the Modules section the "k most semantically similar prompts" is probably just standard talk about embeddings and kNN (nearest neighbors). k might as well be 1, because the vector stores / kNN search will return results in descending score order, thus the first result will likely be best.
